# Runaway memory usage with Selenium using PhantomJS

Tags: python, linux, selenium, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I have written a script in Python that iterates over a long list of webpages and gathers data, using Selenium and PhantomJS as the webdriver (since I'm running it on a remote terminal machine running Linux, and needed to use a headless browser). For short jobs, e.g. where it has to iterate over a few pages, there are no issues. However, for longer jobs, where it has to iterate through a longer list of pages, I see the memory usage increase dramatically over time, each time a new page is loaded. Eventually after about 20 odd pages the script is killed due to memory overflow.

Here is how I initialize my browser -

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://someurl.com/'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
```

The page has next buttons and I iterate through the pages by finding the xpath for the 'Next >' button -

```
next_xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Next >')]"
next_link  = browser.find_element_by_xpath(next_xpath)
next_link.click()
```

I have tried clearing cookies and cache for the PhantomJS browser in the following ways -

```
browser.get('javascript:localStorage.clear();')
browser.get('javascript:sessionStorage.clear();')
browser.delete_all_cookies()
```

However none of these has had any impact on memory usage. When I use the Firefox driver, on my local machine it works without any issues, though it should be noted that my local machine has much more memory than the remote server.

My apologies if any crucial information is missing. Please feel free to let me know how I can make my question more comprehensive.

Comment: Did you get this fixed in the end? Having a problem on my EC2 with PhatomJS hogging memory and causing no scripts to run after script has run 6 or so times. Requiring a reboot of instance

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out what was going on. Just ended up using an instance with more RAM. If you can use a Windows instance I think you might have more luck. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @merch89 A potential solution might involve not using PhantomJS as a webdriver at all. You could try running Xvfb and use any non-headless (Graphical?) browser instead. I haven't tried it myself but this link might prove useful: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Answer (score 0):

If Headless browser is working for you, I would like to suggest a solution which helped me solve similar memory issue. 
Use [AWS Lamda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) as your server, use parallel execution library [xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/) and bingo you would never face a memory issue as Lamada is managed service, Make sure to upload your captured data to S3 and clean up temp directory on lamda. (I have already implemented this in one of my project and works like a charm)